# what does the "SPI_LOOP" mode meaning of spidev?

Tags: linux, spi

when I read spidev_test.c code, I don't understand, what does the SPI_LOOP stand for?

```
case 'l':
                   mode |= SPI_LOOP;
                   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

It stands for a **loopback mode**, altough indeed, at the moment it is not present in the kernel Documentation. Nevertheless it is indicated by a comment next to the constant definition in [`linux/spi/spi.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/spi/spi.h)